# How do I keep the plastic window insulators sealed when the window has a sill?

Tags: sealing, windows, winterizing

Last winter I covered my windows in my apartment with a window sealing kit so keep out any drafts. The winds and temperatures are pretty extreme around here and the plastic would peel away from some sections.

The windows are inset into the wall and don't have any trim around them besides at the bottom where the sill sticks into the room. This creates a problem because I don't have a good way to seal around the sill so I had to just stick the plastic to the top of it. The wind and temperature causes the tape to peel up a lot easier in this setup because of the angle the tape is stuck. I don't really see any other way around it.

Any ideas for how I can set this up better to make sure this thing stays completely sealed through the winter?

[image: Window sill] (This picture I stole from http://abillco.com/sills-wooden-mdf-pine-oak-window-stained-painted/index.htm)

Comment: Does this have to be from the inside?  You could use a thicker plastic and cover the window from the outside.  Not sure if this is an option for you, as the thicker plastic will most likely interrupt the view through the window.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like it would work but its involved.  I do what you do and use the double stick tape on the flat top of the sill.  Then before I shrink the plastic I get normal clear packaging tape and go around the whole window again.  I get a lot of draft and condensation and over the years this technique evolved and seems to work.

Comment: I will give both methods a try this winter and come back to see how it turned out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with an idea earlier today.

If I put the plastic over the window and then put a board over top the piece that is hanging over the sill, I can stick that down and then put a board (maybe a meter stick?) on top of it. I can keep this board tight by using some clamps (probably those clamps used for holding down table cloths on picnic tables). I believe this might do the trick although it is a little extra work. The nice thing is that it's not permanent and it sounds like it would be inexpensive.